# Vector.size() producing an unexpectedly large number

Tags: c++, vector

I have this program which fills a vectors with float values, ensuring each vector (bin) has less than a sum of 1.0 when the float values are totaled. I discovered through debugging that the program is halting when it tries to add values of a vector to a float. The reason is because the for loop is running more times than elements that exist in the vector. I inserted a cout to check the value of the size, and am getting a very large number (95 million something)

```
//Bin packing algorithm
//Takes float values which are <1 and packs them into bins.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int uint;

bool gt( float a, float b )
{
   return b < a;
}

int main()
{
   list< float > S; 
   while( ! cin.eof() )
   {
      float value;
      if( cin >> value && ! cin.eof() )
      {
      assert( value > 0.0 && value <= 1.0 );
         S.push_back( value );
      }
   }

   uint n = S.size();
   uint operations = 0;

   vector< vector< float > > bins;
   S.sort( gt );

   float currentitem;
   float binsum; 

   uint totalbins = 0; 
   uint currentbin; 

   vector<float> tempbin;
   while(S.size() != 0)
   {
      currentitem = S.front();
      S.pop_front();
      currentbin = 0;
      while(currentitem != 0 && totalbins > currentbin)
      {
         currentbin++;
         bintotal = 0;
         for(uint i=0; i < bins[currentbin].size(); i++) 
         {
            cout << "i=" << i <<" bins[currentbin].size()=" << bins[currentbin].size() <<  endl;
            binsum += bins[currentbin][i]; //THIS IS WHERE THE DEBUGGER POINTS. bins[currentbin].size() is producing the 95 million garbage value.
         }
         if((binsum + currentitem) <= 1)
         {
            currentitem = 0;
            bins[currentbin].push_back(currentitem);
         }
      }
      if(currentitem != 0)
      {
         totalbins++;
         tempbin.push_back(currentitem);
         bins.push_back(tempbin);
         tempbin.clear();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't see `bins` being used anywhere before you use `bins[currentbin].size()`. Also, I'd change your loop to `while (std::cin >> value)`.

Comment: Is this minimal? And what values can we put in to reproduce the error?

Comment: why dont you just use [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bins[currentbin]` in the `for` loop access invalid bin as `currentbin` variable is already incremented. You need to `currentbin++` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Actually, at the end of the `while` loop, since its also used in the `if` which follows the `for`